# Difficulty grabbing links inside HTML with scrapy

Tags: html, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I asked a similar question here,

[Trouble getting correct Xpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32116534/trouble-getting-correct-xpath)

but it only got me so far.

I need to grab the links and I understand that [Scrapy](http://scrapy.org/) needs to verify the HTML. This is the HTML

```
class="shopthepost-widget" data-widget-id="708473" data-widget-uid="1"><div id="stp-55d44feabd0eb" class="stp-outer stp-no-controls ">
    <a class="stp-control stp-left stp-hidden">&lt;</a>
    <div class="stp-inner">
        <div class="stp-slide" style="left: -0%">
                        <a href="http://rstyle.me/iA-n/zzhv34c_" target="_blank" rel="nofollow" class="stp-product " data-index="0">
                <span class="stp-help"></span>
                <img src="//images.rewardstyle.com/img?v=2.13&amp;p=n_24878713">
                            </a>
                        <a href="http://rstyle.me/iA-n/zzhvw4c_" target="_blank" rel="nofollow" class="stp-product " data-index="1">
                <span class="stp-help"></span>
                <img src="//images.rewardstyle.com/img?v=2.13&amp;p=n_24878708">
                            </a>
```

So I tried

```py
for widget in response.xpath("//div[@class='shopthepost-widget']"):
  print response.xpath('.//*[@class="shopthepost-widget"]//a/@href').extract()
```

This yields nothing back but if I replace `href` with `text()` then it yields all attributes inside the HTML. This is not what I need. I want only the links and I need them to be passed to an item.

This has got me completely stumped. All help will be met with near infinite thanks.

Comment: There is no javascript here.. All I see is html and python.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Trouble getting correct Xpath](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32116534/trouble-getting-correct-xpath)

Comment: Don't post duplicate questions which are only small updates to your original. Duplicate questions spread out answers and information on a topic across multiple posts, making it harder for others to find an answer and wastes people time re-providing answers you've already been provided.

Answer (score 1):

Again, I can tell you the same what [I have told you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32116997/3941341) for your previous question:

When you load the site in your browser, the JavaScript is executed between the `div`s having `@class='shopthepost-widget'`.

When you load the site with Scrapy, the JavaScript does not get executed and stays the same as it is -- and you do not get any results nor `a` tags inside the previously mentioned `div`s.

```
<div class="shopthepost-widget" data-widget-id="708473">
    <script type="text/javascript">!function(d,s,id){var e, p = /^http:/.test(d.location) ? 'http' : 'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)) {e = d.createElement(s);e.id = id;e.src = p + '://' + 'widgets.rewardstyle.com' + '/js/shopthepost.js';d.body.appendChild(e);}if(typeof window.__stp === 'object') if(d.readyState === 'complete') {window.__stp.init();}}(document, 'script', 'shopthepost-script');</script>
    <br>
    <div class="rs-adblock">
        <img onerror="this.parentNode.innerHTML='Disable your ad blocking software to view this content.'" src="//assets.rewardstyle.com/images/search/350.gif" style="height: 15px; width: 15px;"><noscript>JavaScript is currently disabled in this browser. Reactivate it to view this content.</noscript>
    </div>
</div>
```

So it is obvious that you do not get any results with your XPath because there is no result you would need.

However you could use Chrome for example and look at the XHR requests which are sent when you load the site. They seem to contain the results you are looking for. After you find the request you can emulate it, send it as a `Request` or loading it and then you can parse it.